# How to run this complex ffmpeg command in python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm working on a python script to automate sound and video clip processing. So far I've been able to run ffmpeg commands in python using subprocess, e.g:

```
#extract video audio
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'video.mp4', 'vid_audio.mp3'])
```

However, I can't seem to get the following command split into a list that works with subprocess.

```
#merge two audio tracks with scaled volume
ffmpeg -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=.3[A];[1:a] [A]amerge[out]" -map [out] -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 audiofinal.mp3
```

Any help on how to split the above command into a list that works with subprocess would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the same exact command work if you run it manually, unscripted in a command-line interface?

Comment: yep, works fine if I run it in the command line